# Calling a class from a submodule inside a class in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a following modules structure:

```
folder '/games/unreal_tournament'

module Games
  module UnrealTournament
    class System
     ...
    end
  end
end

folder '/games'

module Games
  class Action
    UnrealTournament::System
  end
end
```

When I try to call the UnrealTournament::System inside the Action class, I get a FATAL: NameError(uninitialized constant UnrealTournament::System).

I don't get this error running the rails app locally. But when I access my app on the server, it gives me the above error. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Where is `/games` located relative to rails root directory? It appears to be an autoloading issue.

Comment: Its inside a lib folder in rails root folder. Here is the structure: project/lib/games... where project is my rails project folder.